# What is the 3.5mm port standard in RPi3?

Tags: pi-3, composite-video

What is the 3.5mm port standard in Raspberry Pi 3?
Is it CTIA or OMTP or any other standard? Mainly I want to know, which one is grounded? Say, **tip ring ring sleeve** = <**1 2 3 4**> respectively.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Raspberry-spy.co.uk](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-5mm-audiovideo-jack/) lists the configuration of the 4-pole A/V jack of the Pi B+ the following way (added testpins PP on the Pi 3 for conveniance, note that according to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=89522&p=628505&hilit=pp1#p628505) and [this](http://ozzmaker.com/testing-points-raspberry-pi/) the same pads are available on the Pi 2B and B+, thanks @mayhem):

- Sleeve - Composite video (PP24, according to [Raspberry Pi 3 test pads](https://sudomod.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=1491), though not listed in the official schematics.)
- Ring 2 - Ground (PP6, among others)
- Ring 1 - Audio-Right (also PP26)
- Tip - Audio-Left (also PP25)

Since it features the composite video it is neither OMTP nor CTIA as those would include a microphone instead. Besides that the pin ordering of the audio and GND pins follow the CTIA system.

From the official schematics of the Raspberrypi Foundation ([3B_V1.2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3b_1p2_reduced.pdf) and [B+_V1.2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_1bplus_1p2_reduced.pdf)) we find that both the Pi 3 (upper figure) and the B+ (lower figure) share the same configuration.

[image: Pi-3]
[image: Pi-Plus]

Comment: PP24 should be the AV pin, but always measure with a meter or other means first before soldering/using. there are listings on the web to help you narrow down test points.. just always confirm them first. one listing... http://ozzmaker.com/testing-points-raspberry-pi/