# Reusing old laptop speakers

Tags: pi-2, hardware, audio, electronics

The speakers are salvaged from an old Toshiba mini nb520 laptop.
How could I go forward to use these speakers? Will I have to write my own drivers? Will it be worth the work? What electronic components will I have to buy?

Update: They are 2 watt speakers.

[image: Laptop speakers]

Comment: Good news: no writing of a driver required, just use ALSA. As for the hardware you could connect the speakers to the 3.5 mm audio out jack ([pin out](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66472/19949)) but it might (or might not) be of insufficient volume. In that case you'll need an amplifier as the linked dupe suggests.

Comment: Ordered two pam8403 amplifiers for less than a dollar. 
Although they are 3W and not 2W as my speakers are, will this pose an issue?

Comment: Not a problem, just don't [turn it up to eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven).