# Broadcast VHF or UHF to CRT TV

Tags: pi-3, signal, television-tuner

I picked up this TV and thought it may be fun to use it with a Raspberry Pi.

https://www.cnet.com/products/spectra-52-bw-5-crt-tv/

However, I soon realized the only way to get a video signal to the TV is via VHF or UHF signals.  The only inputs to the TV are an antenna and a headphone jack.

I did find information for the Pi TV Hat:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-tv-hat/

However, it doesn't look like it can broadcast UHF or VHF.  I tried some Google searching but can't find much info for RPi and UHF or VHF.

I do realize there are laws governing broadcasting UHF/VHF but I'm only planning to do very short range transmission, like from across a room so about 15 feet or 5 meters max.

Does anyone have information on a good direction I can take with this project or is this simply a futile cause?

I do understand the resolution of the TV is low.  I don't care about that.  I just want the effect of displaying video on this small TV.

Comment: that sounds like too much work and expense to get a small low resolution monochrome display

Comment: I don't care about the resolution.  Its more about the effect.  I just to display videos on the TV.  I understand the resolution is going to be low.

Comment: @Justin, I realize the specs page doesn't talk about it, but I have *never* seen an NTSC TV that didn't have an antenna hookup (75ohm coax and/or 300ohm screw terminals).  Are either of those connections on the rear of the unit?  If not, this is going to be much tougher.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I did some research and realized I misunderstood the antenna jack a bit.  I think I could use these two to convert the HDMI signal to RF and then use the adapter to connect to the 1/8 inch jack at the back of the TV.  What do you think?
HDMI to RF

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07DHM23VQ/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A2BL7E35I43FYZ&psc=1

RF to 18 inch jack

https://www.amazon.com/Pigtail-Extension-SO-239-Monitor-Antenna/dp/B07MNZ3TWS/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=rf+to+1%2F8+inch+jack&qid=1564583088&s=gateway&sr=8-4

Comment: Do you have any photo of the jack or documentation?  I would not expect an "antenna jack" on a NTSC TV receiver.  That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Here is a link for the TV.

https://www.cnet.com/products/spectra-52-bw-5-crt-tv/

Comment: All Raspberries can produce an analog TV signal in PAL/NTSC 50/60Hz - you should be able to use that with nothing more than a cable. You'll need to solder in the cable on a RPi Zero or Zero 2. You may need to bypass the TV's tuner but that should be relatively easy to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simple way is to use the Pi's composite video output and a "Composite to RF modulator" sometimes referred to as "RCA RF modulator" since the composite A/V is using a [RCA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector). These devices are independent of the Pi and could be used with any composite source. One would reasonably assume those devices will comply with all relevant regulations on broadcasting. (I will not recommend a specific product but you'll find a few online starting at about $10.)

Note that the Pi 3 has a composite video out that is routed to the sleeve of the 3.5 mm Audio/Video jack, see my answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66472/19949). There is no need to use an additional HDMI to RCA converter.

Comment: I see.  Since I have a RPi 3, I'd like to use the HDMI out.  I'm thinking of something like this:

HDMI to RCA Convertor:
https://www.amazon.com/HDMI-RCA-Cable-All-One/dp/B01KW3MU1G

RCA To RF Modulator:
https://www.amazon.com/RCA-Compact-RF-Modulator-CRF907A/dp/B0014KKV7W

But then comes the question of getting the video signal to the TV.  Would I be able to attach an antenna to the RF Modulator to broadcast the signal to the TV?

Comment: @Justin I wasn't sure you were going for *High Definition* qualitity on a five inch CRT ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!  In the end, it was simpler than I thought.  Basically, through a series of cables and adapters, you can simply convert the HDMI output to an RF signal then send it directly into the TV's antenna jack.  Then you adjust the frequency and you have a display!

The quality isn't the best and the color is only black and white but it does look really cool.

I've updated my website and added this to my projects.  If you click on RPi CRTV Monitor, you can see photos of the connections and video output.

https://justinckirk.com/pages/projects.html

Comment: Of course an adapter from the format you have to the format you need is the solution.

Comment: Pictures are not on line anymore